# Not supplying enough data to HAL while using picasso to download image

Tags: java, android, image, picasso

I'm trying to download the using `Picasso` into `internal storage` but it's showing not supplying enough data to `HAL`.

```
public void downloadImage( String url) {

    String filename= UUID.randomUUID().toString()+".jpg";

    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url)
            .into(new Imagedownloader(anime_relativelayout,lottieAnimationView,
                    getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),filename,"image desc"));


}

public class Imagedownloader implements Target {

  private RelativeLayout anime_relativelayout;
  private LottieAnimationView lottieAnimationView;
  String name;
  String desc;



  public Imagedownloader(RelativeLayout anime_relativelayout, LottieAnimationView lottieAnimationView,
                       ContentResolver contentResolver, String filename, String s) {

    this.contentResolverWeakReference = new WeakReference<ContentResolver>(contentResolver);
    this.name = filename;
    this.desc = s;
    this.lottieAnimationView=lottieAnimationView;
    this.anime_relativelayout=anime_relativelayout;
  }

  @Override
  public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

    ContentResolver resolver=contentResolverWeakReference.get();
    //AlertDialog dialog=alertDialogWeakReference.get();

    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(resolver,bitmap,name,desc);


    //lottieAnimationView.pauseAnimation();
    //anime_relativelayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //dialog.dismiss();

  }

  @Override
  public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

  }
}
```